# NO DisplayMemberChanged in LookUpEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Seems to be there is no event for display member change in `LookUpEdit`.

If the popup details have two option withe same `ValueMember` value but with different `DisplayMember` value, even though you select different display value, you wont be able to see that updated in the combo box as the `ValueMember` value is same for both the keys. Which causes the `EditValueChanged` event to be triggered.

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the [DevExpress documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEditBase_ValueMembertopic):

> ValueMember is a key property you need to assign when setting up the
>   lookup editor.

If you violate this constraint by specifying a non-unique value then the first row is always returned (I don't believe that behavior is documented so I expect it could change in the future).  To resolve the issue, specify a unique key as the `lookUpEdit1.Properties.ValueMember`.

Answer (score 0):

As for many post on [DevExpress site](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CQ57857.aspx) the LookUpEdit has no SelectedIndexChanged event.
There are 2 viable options for you:

1. Use the GridLookUpEdit in conjunction with the FocusedRowChanged event
2. Review your code: the EditValue is supposed to be unique. Is there any way you can manage your scenario server side sending different EditValues for each LookUp line?

Answer (score 0):

LookUpEdit in deveexpress have two properties
ValueMember & 
DisplayMember

Assign the value which you want to display in LookUpEdit and
value which you want to save (in database) assign it to ValueMember